# Match or connect two csv files as datasets with python

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have two datasets in csv format. These datasets have different columns (number of columns and even their headers) although I know some of them are common, my issue is finding common column(s). The basic solution is testing one by one or all combinations of columns in two datasets. Is there any solution, model or approach to read both of them and find common column(s) to present maximum number of records of matching? For example with python or pandas.

Comment: Hi. You should include in your question an example input and output, as well as the detail of what you have attempted so far. This will make it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that with the intersection in pandas. Basically, you read both the csv in two dataframes and then find the intersection of columns, which will give you call the common columns

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")
common_cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
```